Always throw an Exception "Exception has occurred: TypeError: xxxx.default is not a constructor"
Using TypeScript, I's using EventEmitter to listen the events exposed by node:events.
import EventEmitter from 'events';
const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();


With the TypeScript application (not using NestJS). No any exceptions
But when I switch to use Nestjs, it always throw an expected exceptions Exception has occurred: TypeError: events_1.default is not a constructor 

Here is my tsconfig.json


{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES2021",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
  }
}



So, how can I find out the exactly reason?

Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text (using code formatting), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and many more reasons. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data. See [mre] on what code is required.

Add the setting "esModuleInterop": true in tsconfig.json file, then everything worked nicely.


{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    ...
  }
}



